# Can I hide the tab bar's fading edge using ActionBarSherlock?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, tabbar, actionbarsherlock

I want to hide the tab bar's fading edge, but I'm using ActionBarSherlock.

```
<item name="android:fadingEdge">none</item>
<item name="android:fadingEdgeLength">0dp</item>
<item name="android:requiresFadingEdge">none</item>
```

This is what I'm setting in my style for actionBarTabBarStyle, and nothing happens pre-4.0. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding copies of the style entries without the `android:` prefix?

```
<item name="android:fadingEdge">none</item>
<item name="fadingEdge">none</item>
<item name="android:fadingEdgeLength">0dp</item>
<item name="fadingEdgeLength">0dp</item>
<item name="android:requiresFadingEdge">none</item>
<item name="requiresFadingEdge">none</item>
```

This is described in the "Theming" section of the ABS [Migration documentation](http://actionbarsherlock.com/migration.html).